# WPF Binding to Child Collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collections

if the parent's datasource has a child property that is a collection (let's say it is called ChildCollection) is there a trick to reference it?

So, this code sample is basically what I am attempting to do. But when I use this approach I do not get any data to my child controls.

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <sample:Data x:Key="MyData" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Canvas DataContext="{StaticResource MyData}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <My:UserControl DataContext="{Binding ChildCollection}" />
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

My dependency property looks like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ButtonList), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(DataChanged)));
public DoubleCollection Data
{
    get { return (DoubleCollection)GetValue(DataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
}
static void DataChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext = e.NewValue;
}
public void SetData(IEnumerable data)
{
    (View as CollectionViewSource).Source = data;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code right, you want the collection to be in the UserControl's DataProperty.

To achieve this, you have to do the Binding like this:

```
 <Canvas DataContext="{StaticResource MyData}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    <My:UserControl Data="{Binding ChildCollection}" />
 </Canvas>
```

Instead of:

```
<Canvas DataContext="{StaticResource MyData}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
    <My:UserControl DataContext="{Binding ChildCollection}" />
 </Canvas>
```

Hope this is helpful. Also: I dont know if a canvas inherits it's DataContext to childs. Use a Panel instead (Grid/Stackpanel/WrapPanel).

Jan

Comment: PS: also try DynamicResource instead of StaticResource for your DataContext Binding on the Panel.

Comment: Canvas is derived from Panel. All FrameworkElements provide DataContext inheritance.

Comment: Thats not right. The Frame Component does not inherit its DataContext. As i did not test it with Canvas, i mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working sample with a user control (ButtonList) that has a DP of type `IEnumerable<double>` and creates a button for each double value. Compare it to you code to see what you are doing incorrectly.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlDemo.ButtonList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:UserControlDemo="clr-namespace:UserControlDemo"
    Name="_buttonList">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControlDemo:ButtonList}}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace UserControlDemo
{
    public partial class ButtonList : UserControl
    {
        public ButtonList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IEnumerable<double> Data
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable<double>)GetValue(DataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data",
                                        typeof(IEnumerable<double>), 
                                        typeof(ButtonList), 
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<double>()));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 <UserControlDemo:ButtonList Data="{Binding Path=Numbers}" />
```